# How to delete the java.awt.Point [...] on console output

Tags: java

I'm using `java.awt.Point`, and when I try to return `Point` object it prints out `java.awt.Point [x =.., y=...]`. How can I get rid of the `java.awt.Point`, let the method just return only `x` and `y`?

Comment: Write your own method to get the x/y from the point and format it the way you want

Comment: Side note, you're seeing the result of the PrintStream call Point's toString method

Comment: No, you can't monkey-patch in Java. That method does what it does and you can't change it. But why would you want to? Just write your own function.

Comment: I mean this is my method in my class:
(public Point intersectionPoint(LineEquation other ){
//...
Point b = new Point (x,y);
 return b; 
})
so when I use in the client code, it just print out on the console something like :
[link](java.awt.Point[x=0,y=-22].) 
I don't want to rewrite the Point class with new toString method, just looking for simplest way to get rid of java.awt.Point[] or become something like (x,y)..

Thank yoi @Chris Martin and  MadProgrammer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your question is still actual (I hope that not and you've found the solution =) ) 

But just in case:
When you write something like `someObject.getLocation()` to the string, you're adding a Point object. This means it is converted to string with `toString()` method exactly for `java.awt.Point`, which looks like:

```
public String toString() {
return "java.awt.Point[x=" + x + ",y=" + y + "]";
```

}

But you can write your own, alternative toString(), like:

```
// Get the object's location.
Point location = someObject.getLocation();

// Here goes your method
String locationString = "[" + location.x + "," + location.y + "]";

// Then just print it
System.out.println(lcoationString);
```